# Why does Rx buffer continuously perform method when buffer contains no items?

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive

I have a Rx Observable that acts as a buffer. Right now it performs the method in Subscribe either when it gets 10 items, or after 100 milliseconds, whichever comes first.

I noticed that my method is continuously being called every 100 ms, even when there are no items in the buffer, which surprised me. It's simple enough to just make my method return immediately if it receives no items from the buffer, but I thought it was weird that it's just churning away in the background like that.

Why is this? How do you recommend I best deal with this? I am a complete newbie to Rx, so maybe I'm doing something weird. Here's a simplified version of my code:

```
private Subject<KeyValuePair<int, Action<MyData>>> serverRequests;

public MyBufferClass(IMyServer server, IScheduler scheduler)
{
    this.serverRequests = new Subject<KeyValuePair<int, Action<MyData>>>();

    this.serverRequests
        .Buffer(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100), 10, scheduler)
        .Subscribe(buffer => GetMultipleItemsFromServer(buffer));
}   

public void GetSingleItemFromServer(int id, Action<MyData> callback)
{
    this.serverRequests.OnNext(new KeyValuePair<int, Action<MyData>>(id, callback));
}

public void GetMultipleItemsFromServer(IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<int, Action<MyData>>> idsWithCallbacks)
{
    if (idsWithCallbacks.IsNullOrEmpty()) return;

    this.server.GetMultipleItems(idsWithCallbacks)
}
```

In my tests, if I call GetSingleItemFromServer 5 times and then advance my TestScheduler by 1000 ms, I thought GetMultipleItemsFromServer would only be called once, but it gets called 10 times.

Comment: What do you expect to happen when the timeout you specified elapses without any items being available?

Comment: I'd like nothing to happen, essentially.

I understand that some situations you might want it to call the method continuously, but for me the whole point is to only make a single call to the server to reduce traffic. Without doing the null/empty check, I end up calling the server every 100 ms, eek. But perhaps that null/empty check is exactly what I'm *supposed* to do.

Comment: My point is only: If you specify a timeout, then something *has* to happen upon the time running out. If "nothing" should happen, then the timeout serves no purpose in the first place. That said, if you don't care about the length of the timeout but you have to set one you can also set it to some huge value, like an hour or so, so that, when idle, your routine will not run more frequently than once an hour, instead of 10x per sec.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your meaning. I only want "nothing" to happen if there are no items in the buffer. I definitely want something to happen if there are any items in the buffer, and I need it to happen quickly (so I can't set it to a huge value). Basically my client puts requests into the buffer. When that buffer either reaches 10 items or 100 ms elapse, I want to make a batch request to the server. If my client doesn't make any requests, I have no reason to call the server at all.

Comment: In that case, your specification is incomplete: You said that you want something to happen *at least* every 100ms. But I figure what you meant is that you only ever want something to happen if the buffer is *not empty*. "When that buffer either reaches 10 items **or** 100 ms elapse, ..." is exactly what your implementation does. "When that buffer either reaches 10 items, or *it is not empty* and 100 ms elapse, ..." is a different thing.

Comment: Yes, of course that's what I meant, that's literally the point of my question. I said "my method is continuously being called every 100 ms, even when there are no items in the buffer, which surprised me." Instinctively I thought the method in Subscribe() would only be called when serverRequests.OnNext() has been invoked... but that is not the case.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In situations like this an elegant solution can be to use the Where operator straight after the Buffer to filter out any empty results. Something like this:

```
            stream
            .Buffer (...)
            .Where (x => x.Any())
            .Subscribe (x => {...}, ex => {...});
```

As to why Buffer acts like this, I suppose it's better to surface an empty collection and allow the consumer to choose what to do with it, than to swallow it and deny that opportunity.

On a separate note, I wouldn't have your server call within the subscribe block. I think it's a better idea to have any asynchronous operations as a part of the Rx stream composition itself, and to restrict the Subscribe action to any lightweight operations that deal with the final result, i.e. updating the UI, logging success/failure etc. Something like this:

```
(from request in serverRequests
            .Buffer (TimeSpan.FromMinutes (1))
            .Where (x => x.Any())
from response in Observable.Start(server.GetMultipleItems(...))
select response)
.Subscribe (x => {}, ex => {});
```

Advantages to this include:

-Being able to use further Rx operators on your server call, such as Timeout(), Retry(), Catch(), etc.

-Being able to handle any pipeline errors within the Subscribe() overload

-Independent scheduling of the pipeline and the Subscribe action with SubscribeOn()/ObserveOn().

Comment: **This is not an elegant solution at all regarding CPU consumption!!**
CPU is consuming every minute even if nothing appears. The `Where` only masks the intervals produced by `Buffer`.
This is this kind of code that could cost you a lot on a platform such as azure where you pay the CPU you are consuming.

Comment: The performance impact of calling .Any() once per minute is so small, CPU consumption had not even crossed my mind. I'd favour readability over any performance concerns in this situation.

Comment: Not all buffers are one minute, with a 10ms window, for example, the overhead is much higher.

Answer (score 11):

Perhaps try it like this:

```
public MyBufferClass(IMyServer server, IScheduler scheduler)
{
    this.serverRequests = new Subject<KeyValuePair<int, Action<MyData>>>();

    this.serverRequests
        .GroupByUntil(x => 1, x => Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000)))
        .SelectMany(x => x.ToArray())
        .Subscribe(buffer => GetMultipleItemsFromServer(buffer));
}
```

That doesn't give you empty results.

And the answer to your question regarding `.Buffer(...)` - that's the way it has been designed. Nothing more complicated than that.

Comment: This is the right answer according to me: this acts approximately as Buffer.Where(something) (triggering is not as regular as buffer but this is probably not expected in this case), but without consuming much CPU than necessary. Thanks!

Comment: This should be the right answer to avoid consuming more CPU than required.