# Rx Buffer without empty calls to subscriber

Tags: c#, buffer, system.reactive, batching

In my WPF application using .Net 4.6 I have an event which fires new data points at a high rate (several hundred per second), but not all the time. This data is displayed in a chart.

I would like to update the chart every 50 ms and not after each new data point.
To achieve that I though of using `Buffer(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(50))` from Rx, which in theory works fine. BUT my subscriber is also called every 50 ms if no new data points are created which is not exactly what I want.

I created a little sample application to test that out:

```
using System;
using System.Reactive.Linq;

namespace RxTester
{
    public class Program
    {
        private static event EventHandler TheEvent;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var observable = Observable.FromEvent<EventHandler, EventArgs>(h => (s, e) => h(e), h => TheEvent += h, h => TheEvent -= h);
            var subscriber = observable.Buffer(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000))
                .Subscribe(e => Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()}: {e.Count} elements received..."));

            var random = new Random();
            var timer = new System.Timers.Timer(2000)
                {
                    AutoReset = true,
                    Enabled = true
                };
            timer.Elapsed += (s, e) =>
                {
                    var amount = random.Next(1, 10);
                    for (int i = 0; i < amount; ++i)
                        TheEvent?.Invoke(null, null);
                };

            Console.ReadLine();

            timer.Enabled = false;
            subscriber.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

You need to add the "Rx-Linq" NuGet package for it to run or use the following Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/TV5tD4

There you see several "0 elements received" which is what I would like to avoid. I know I could simple check for `e.Count == 0`, but as I use multiple of such buffers this does not seem optimal to me.

**Is there a way to only create new buffered blocks of element if elements are available?**
I am also open for other approaches to solve my problem of batching events on a time basis - I already looked into TPL Dataflows `BatchBlock`, but that seems to only support count based block sizes.

Comment: Somewhat related: [RX - Group/Batch bursts of elements in an observable sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29858974/rx-group-batch-bursts-of-elements-in-an-observable-sequence) and [Why does Rx buffer continuously perform method when buffer contains no items?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30081331/why-does-rx-buffer-continuously-perform-method-when-buffer-contains-no-items)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Once again we can use the powerful `GroupByUntil` method to create this extension

```
public static IObservable<IList<TSource>> BufferWhenAvailable<TSource>
                                          (this IObservable<TSource> source, 
                                           TimeSpan threshold)
{
    return source.Publish( sp => 
                    sp.GroupByUntil(_ => true, _ => Observable.Timer(threshold))
                      .SelectMany(i => i.ToList()));

}
```

Comment: Thanks for this - seems to work fine. BUT `return source.GroupByUntil(_ => true, _ => Observable.Timer(threshold)).SelectMany(g => g.ToList());` seems to also work just fine - what is the benefit of the `Observable.Create` around it?

Comment: @ChrFin in this case there is no benefit. I'll edit the answer :)

Comment: ...and if you think about it `Observable.FromEvent` is always hot. So `Publish` could also be omitted.

Comment: Nice. Is the `Publish` part required?

Comment: @LeeCampbell in this case there is no shared subscription. So no it isn't necessary.

Answer (score 4):

The standard way of doing this is simply

```
.Buffer(period)
.Where(buffer=>buffer.Any())
```

So effectively doing what you want to avoid `(count==0)`. However, this check is very cheap and I would imagine if far cheaper than the other cost involved i.e. Scheduling. The only concern might be the amount allocations that are happening (every 50ms creating a `List<T>`) and then the impending GC Gen0 pressure that may build.

Comment: Thanks for your input, but `The only concern might be the amount allocations that are happening` is why I want to avoid this, as I possible have multiple of these buffers at once...

Comment: I hear ya. Sounds like it would a good one to add to the tool box. If I come up with a soln to this will get back to you https://github.com/LeeCampbell/RxCookbook/issues/27

Comment: @LeeCampbell if I understand correctly: even if you prevent `Buffer(TimeSpan)` from yielding empty buffers, the solution is still different. The buffers are "started" based on the timer, not when a new value arrives.

Comment: Yes. Buffer will use constant cadence windows. If you want to start buffers based on when values arrive, then you probably want to look into the `GroupJoin` operator http://introtorx.com/Content/v1.0.10621.0/17_SequencesOfCoincidence.html and produce something custom yourself.

Comment: Upvote on supertopii's answer (though I would like to see the supporting unit tests)