# RxJava buffering - ignoring zero items

Tags: java, rx-java, reactive-programming, reactivex

Here's the code that I have for buffering and converting incoming events:

```
public Publisher<Collection<EventTO>> logs(String eventId) {
    ConnectableObservable<Event> connectableObservable = eventsObservable
        .share().publish();
    connectableObservable.connect();

    connectableObservable.toFlowable(BackpressureStrategy.BUFFER)
        .filter(event -> event.getId().equals(eventId))
        .buffer(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS, 50)
        .map(eventsMapper::mapCollection);
}
```

The problem here is that `Flowable` returns an empty list each second although there are no events published to the `eventsObservable`.

Is there a way to hold `.buffer` until there is at least one object?

**Note:**
Looks like there is a way to do it in C# (described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30090185/668148). 
But how can it be done in Java?

Comment: can you use `.distinctUntilChanged` after `buffer( ... )`, or `.filter(collection -> !collection.isEmpty)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by Mark Keen, `.distinctUntilChanged` does the trick.

So the following code will push the list of events if there are 1+ items after buffering:

```
connectableObservable.toFlowable(BackpressureStrategy.BUFFER)
    .filter(event -> event.getId().equals(eventId))
    .buffer(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS, 50)
    .distinctUntilChanged()             // <<<======  
    .map(eventsMapper::mapCollection);
```